# POD Security Policy Evaluation order (multiple roles)

Tags: security, kubernetes

Running 1.15 on AWS EKS.

By default AWS provides `eks.privileged` PSP (documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-security-policy.html). This is assigned to all authenticated users.

I then create a more restrictive PSP `eks.restricted`:

```
---
# restricted pod security policy

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    eks.amazonaws.com/component: pod-security-policy
  name: eks.restricted
spec:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  allowedCapabilities:
  - '*'
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  hostPorts:
  - max: 65535
    min: 0
  runAsUser:
    rule: MustRunAsNonRoot
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  volumes:
  - '*'
```

The above is a non-mutating PSP. I also modify the default `eks.privilged` PSP to make it modifying by adding the following annotations

```
seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: docker/default
seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName: docker/default
```

Finally I update the clusterrole to add in the new PSP I created:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: eks:podsecuritypolicy:privileged
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    eks.amazonaws.com/component: pod-security-policy
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resourceNames:
  - eks.privileged
  - eks.restricted
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  verbs:
  - use
```

What this accomplishes is that `eks.restricted` becomes the default PSP do to the fact that it is non-mutating (https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#policy-order and the  order of the list doesn't matter).

That is great. But what I am trying to accomplish is create a single namespace that defaults to `eks.restricted` while all others default to `eks.privileged`.

I attempted to do this as such.

First I removed `eks.restricted` from ClusterRole `eks:podsecuritypolicy:privileged` so that eks.privileged is now the cluster wide default. Within my namespace I created a new role

```
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    eks.amazonaws.com/component: pod-security-policy
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
  name: eks:podsecuritypolicy:restricted
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resourceNames:
  - eks.restricted
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  verbs:
  - use
```

This Role grants use to PSP `eks.restricted`. I then bound this new Role to a ServiceAccount within my example namespace.

```
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: psp-restricted
  namespace: psp-example
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: eks:podsecuritypolicy:restricted
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: privileged-sa
  namespace: psp-example
```

Finally I created a deployment, which violates PSP `eks.restricted` that uses this serviceAccount

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: centos-deployment
  namespace: psp-example
  labels:
    app: centos
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: centos
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: centos
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: privileged-sa
      containers:
      - name: centos
        #image: centos:centos7
        image: datinc/permtest:0
        command:
          - '/bin/sleep'
          - '60000'
```

My assumption would be that this would function as in my initial example/test at the start of this post. My combined access is to both `eks.privileged` due to it being bound to system:authenticated group and `eks.restricted` bound to the serviceAccount my deployment is running under. Since `eks.restricted` is non-mutating it should be the one that applies and such it should fail to create PODs. But that isn't what happens. The PODs start up just fine.

As a further test I added `eks.privileged` to the SA Role (listed above) expecting it to function like in my original example. It does not, PODs create just fine.

Trying to figure out why this is.

Answer (score 0):

At AWS, your deployment uses ServiceAccount `replicaset-controller` in namespace `kube-system`, so you need to remove this from ClusterRoleBinding `eks:podsecuritypolicy:authenticated` or delete that.

Kindly check this article for the detail :
https://dev.to/anupamncsu/pod-security-policy-on-eks-mp9